# Import ONNX into Android

Tags: java, android, onnx

For a small software project i need to use a trained Neural Network within an Android app. The network was trained in Matlab and exported as ONNX.

Now i need to import the ONNX runtime and use the trained network inside my Android app.

I added the following lines in my build.gradle(module):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.microsoft.onnxruntime:onnxruntime-android:1.15.1'
}
```

But when i try to use the ONNX package in my application the build fails. I am using:

```
import ai.onnxruntime.*;
```

Android Studio indicates, that the package ai.onnxruntime does not exist. Therefor it cannot find symbol class OrtEnvironment, OrtSession etc.

I followed the instructions on the ONNX website, where it states "Add a dependency on com.microsoft.onnxruntime:onnxruntime-android or com.microsoft.onnxruntime:onnxruntime-mobile" as installation instructions for platform Android and API Java

Also when i check the examples on github, there is nothing more in the gradle scripts.

So what am i doing wrong here? What am i missing?

When i click on the error it says "Add library 'Gradle: com.microsoft.onnxruntime:onnxruntime-android:1.15.1@aar' to classpath"

Answer (score 2):

Try without @aar

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.onnxruntime:onnxruntime-android:1.16.0-rc1'
```

Works fine to me